# Snackbar half width on tablet

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-snackbar, floating-action-button

I have problem with setting `Snackbar` on tablet (API 22), on phones (API 23 and 22) it works fine (from edge to edge), even when horizontal.
Result is such Snackbar as below:[image]

FloatingActionButton (support library) also doesn't move (when on phone it does).

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/snackParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_fab"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_fab"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And using in MainActivity

```
private void showMessage(String msg) {
    if(snackParent != null) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(snackParent, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

I have only other resources file with dimensions (fab margin) for tablets (w820dp), styles folder is same between phone and tablet. I have also tried invalidating Android Studio cache.
I use `com.android.support:design:23.0.1` targetSdkVersion=23 and compileSdkVersion=23, buildToolsVersion=23.0.1.

Comment: I think this is the default behavior of snackbar on tablets. check [this](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-snackbar-design-support-library.html) out

Comment: Yeah, I just tested on empty project with older support library versions, targetSdkVersion etc. and all seems to point it is on purpose.
Can you post your replay as answer?

Comment: This might be a bit late but the following works for me : mSnackbar.getView().getLayoutParams().width = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the default behavior of snackbar on tablets. check [this](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-snackbar-design-support-library.html) out .

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do whatever you want with your snackbar. We had the same issue with tablets and we solved like this (e.g. code below is positioning snackbar at top and gives it the full width of the parent)

```
View view = snackbar.getView();

// Position snackbar at top
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: If I use view as above instead of coordinatorLayout, I get CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams error

Answer (score 1):

After digging into code from [github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/res/values/styles.xml). I found one workaround. You just need to add below lines into styles.xml. Change the width as per your requirement

```
<style name="Widget.Design.Snackbar" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="maxActionInlineWidth">500dp</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change number of lines of default textview of Snackbar, you can change following style.

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:maxLines">3</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = snackbarView.getLayoutParams();

```
        if (layoutParams instanceof FrameLayout.LayoutParams) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layoutParams;
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            snackbarView.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else if (layoutParams instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) layoutParams;
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            snackbarView.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layoutParams;
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            snackbarView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't able to solve this issue by using above approach. After looking into the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/9405121f62eee1cb6e188e161031c358b8d9d962/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar)

I added below code into my styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.Design.Snackbar" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:maxWidth">-1px</item>
</style>
```

currently it is set to

```
<item name="android:maxWidth">@dimen/design_snackbar_max_width</item>
<dimen name="design_snackbar_max_width">576dp</dimen>
```